# Remove String contains the words using regex

Tags: regex

Need to remove the below sting from the words using regex. What is the best way:

Input:     MARGET_458459843_hgtb7676

Output Required: 458459843_hgtb7676

The matching "MARGET_" String needs to be removed from the word using regex.

Comment: No need for regex, just find first index of `_` in a string and take a substring starting after posiiton of first occurence of `_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^[^_]+_
Replace: (empty)
```

### Demo

If you really want to match the specific text `MARGET` at the start of each line, then do a find on `^MARGET_` and replace with empty string.

Comment: Thanks for reply but Sometime we are getting without   MARGET_. Currently we are using this expression but i want to remove the only MARGET_ string from the words. If this string MARGET_ not contains, i should not remove anything.

Comment: In that case, just replace `^MARGET_` with empty string.  I tried to give as generic an an answer as possible.

Comment: replace /^[MARGET_]+_/ with ""  --> working fine thanks